# Script (or program) to modify schemas in yaml file

Tags: java, yaml

I need to modify all instances of one specific kind of schema in yaml files. Schema that has anyOf enum and string, I need to erase string and leave only enum.
So from this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    //a lot of different schemas
    NotificationMethod:
      anyOf:
      - type: string
        enum:
          - PERIODIC
          - ONE_TIME
          - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
      - type: string
        description: >
          This string provides forward-compatibility with future
          extensions to the enumeration but is not used to encode
          content defined in the present version of this API.
      description: >
        Possible values are
        - PERIODIC
        - ONE_TIME
        - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
```

I need to receive this:

```
components:
  schemas:
    //a lot of different schemas
    NotificationMethod:
      type: string
      enum:
        - PERIODIC
        - ONE_TIME
        - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
      description: >
        Possible values are
        - PERIODIC
        - ONE_TIME
        - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
```

1. Such correction should be done only in schemas with anyOf that has 2 options: string and enum.
2. Line with anyOf is erased.
3. "- " (dash and whitespace) before leaved "type" is erased.
4. In each line of specification of leaved type two whitespaces are erased.
5. Type "string" and it's description is erased.

How it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```
yq e '(.. | select(has("anyOf")) | select(.anyOf.[] | has("enum"))) as $i |
    $i.description as $d |
    $i = ($i.anyOf.[] | select(has("enum"))) |
    $i.description = $d' test.yaml
```

For your example (minus the illegal `//a lot of different schemas` ), you get this output:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    NotificationMethod:
      type: string
      enum:
        - PERIODIC
        - ONE_TIME
        - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
      description: >
        Possible values are - PERIODIC - ONE_TIME - ON_EVENT_DETECTION
```

Mind that this is totally valid from a YAML perspective as `>` starts a *folded* block scalar where line breaks will be folded into a space. If you want to keep the line breaks in the description where they are, use a literal block scalar instead.

The `yq` command above shows the concept and works for the example but you'll want to fine-tune it to your requirements.